# AngularJS - ng-if on a large amount of values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hello guys,

I would like a div to display only if an unknown (that can be large) amount of conditions are met. Something like :

```
<div ng-if="foreach(arrayOfValues as row) row.username != ''"> nice data</div>
```

So whenever the data is correctly populated and all of it has been received (it's from multiple sources) the bloc of data appears at once.

Thanks ahead !

Comment: i don't understand why you want to do this in html template. It can be done   as a simple js function which will return true of all good or break and return false. Will be more optimized and better. Don't pollute your html so much Please.

Comment: I didn't want to do it in the view, it was just to set the goal, really :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it in your controller:

```
.controller('myController', function($scope){

   $scope.isValid = function(){
      for(var i = 0; i < $scope.arrayOfValues.length; i++){
          if($scope.arrayOfValues.username == '') return false
      }
      return true;
   })  

})
```

HTML inside that controller on the page:

```
<div ng-if="isValid()"> nice data</div>
```

Note that calling a function like this isn't the most efficient, as it has to execute `isValid` every digest cycle. It'd be better to `$watch` your data and set a validity flag on the scope.

EDIT:

Even better, since you say this is just to check if all the data has loaded, use `$q.all` with the data requests to set a `loaded` flag on the scope.

Edit2- the watch solution:

```
.controller('myController', function($scope){
   $scope.loaded = false;

   var clearWatch = $scope.$watch('arrayOfValues', function(){
      $scope.loaded = true
      for(var i = 0; i < $scope.arrayOfValues.length; i++){
          if($scope.arrayOfValues.username == ''){
              $scope.loaded = false;
              break;
          }
      }
      if($scope.loaded){
         clearWatch();
      }
   }, true)

})
```

Comment: That's globally what I thought about. Sadly I can't use $q.all since I don't really have the hand on the promises (using an existing service is not always a good thing, as I'm learning!). Hoped there would be something better to do for performances reasons than using a watcher... Anyway, thanks for your help ! If no better answer comes up I will validate this one.

Comment: Could you not create your own promises using `$q` and resolving in the callbacks of whatever you do have access to?

Comment: Not really, it's an extended factory from a service on which I can't make changes that returns the data... And in the extended factory every element is handled separately. I got a nice answer below though !

Comment: See my edit 2 for the watch solution. Assuming you can't hook into the promises directly to monitor load status, this is the most efficient way I know of.

Comment: I agree. Think I will go with that one.

Comment: Just a minor tweak, throwing in a break will make it considerably faster.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the every() method, and pass a simple checker function that's defined in your scope like so.

```
<div ng-if="arrayOfValues.every(checkValues)"> nice data</div>
```

in your controller, that function will just check each element

```
$scope.checkValues = function(element) { return element; }
```

this returns a truthy or falsy value. An empty string is falsy, so anything that does have a name will return a truthy value. This makes returning the element sufficient in this case.

Here's a working fiddle, with a button that updates the names to show the text

https://jsfiddle.net/5c88pte6/1/

Comment: That looks awesome ! I tried it and it works like a charm. Since I'm still young with Angular, how much would this hurt performances ? and if I want to display a loader while waiting, can I use <div ng-if="!arrayOfValues.every(checkValues)">Loading</div> or will it hurt performances more ?

Comment: This is as inefficient as my `isInvalid` solution. It (and mine) are inefficient because every time angular fires a digest cycle (the thing that make the DOM live update with new scope values), it has to execute the scans to see if the returned value has changed, and thus whether it has a new value to update the DOM with. If you use `$watch` and then destroy the watch once you know it's loaded, it will not have to recheck. Whether it's enough of an issue to warrant a different approach is, of course, subjective. The `!..` will not affect performance.

Comment: From what I see with a console.log it fires multiple times every second !! Not that great, finally :/

Comment: You could do that, yes. As far as performance goes... that depends on the collection size, and how much logic is in the function where you're evaluating true/false. The nice thing about this is you're just returning the element- which makes it pretty lean. To be honest, if your collection size is fairly large, using ng-show/hide is probably a better approach if you're going to be toggling this often. ng-if completely removes the element from the DOM, and has to recreate the scope for it after creation. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf